# add categories to sitemap plugin through the renderSitemap hook

Tags: plugins, plugin-sitemap

I'm trying to setup a sitemap using the [craft-sitemap plugin](https://github.com/joshuabaker/craft-sitemap), however it only covers sections by default and I need to add category groups into it, as half of the URLs are in categories.

I can see the Service Methods section in the docs that says that "There’s several service methods made available to add items to the sitemap."

**Hooks**
`renderSitemap`

Add a renderSitemap method to your plugin to add items via the various service methods listed below.

Here’s an example plugin hook method with comments:

```
addCategoryGroup(CategoryGroupModel $categoryGroup, [$changefreq, [$priority]])
```

Adds all categories in the group to the sitemap.

```
$group = craft()->categories->getGroupByHandle('news');
craft()->sitemap->addCategoryGroup($group);
```

But I'm not sure where to start. Where does the hook code go? As I'm assuming I'd have to create a new file, as it will need to be separate from the sitemap plugin as that will be overwritten if there are any updates.

I would appreciate some advice on this please?

Comment: Just an FYI that the PutYourLightsOn Sitemap plugin handles category groups, Craft Commerce product types and custom URL's out of the box, although it is a commercial plugin: 
https://www.putyourlightson.net/craft-sitemap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to create a separate plugin, which adds the categories to the sitemap in response to the `renderSitemap` hook.

Here's what [your main plugin file](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/setting-things-up#your-primary-plugin-class) will look like. This should get you 90% of the way there; the rest is just organising a few files and folders, which is well-covered by [the official documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/introduction).

```
<?php

/**
 * SitemapCategories
 *
 * @package Craft
 */

namespace Craft;

/**
 * The main SitemapCategories plugin file.
 */
class SitemapCategoriesPlugin extends BasePlugin
{
    /**
     * Returns the plugin name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return Craft::t('Sitemap Categories');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the plugin description.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return Craft::t('Adds categories to the sitemap.');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the plugin’s version number.
     *
     * @return string The plugin’s version number.
     */
    public function getVersion()
    {
        return '0.1.0';
    }

    /**
     * Returns the plugin developer’s name.
     *
     * @return string The plugin developer’s name.
     */
    public function getDeveloper()
    {
        return 'Your name here';
    }

    /**
     * Returns the plugin developer’s URL.
     *
     * @return string The plugin developer’s URL.
     */
    public function getDeveloperUrl()
    {
        return 'https://yourwebsite.com';
    }

    /**
     * Returns a faux schema version, so Craft doesn't attempt to run database
     * updates when the plugin version changes.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSchemaVersion()
    {
        return '0.0.0';
    }

    /**
     * Returns a boolean indicating whether the plugin has settings.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasSettings()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a boolean indicating whether the plugin has it's own control
     * panel section.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasCpSection()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Adds all categories to the sitemap.
     */
    public function renderSitemap()
    {
        $groups = craft()->categories->getAllGroups();

        foreach ($groups as $group) {
            craft()->sitemap->addCategoryGroup($group);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whatever it takes to ensure Brad doesn't get that bounty.